# Trouble retrieving friends data from Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to:

Retrieve a friend list from a user with the friend information:

- Location
- Education
- Name
- Profile picture

The problem is the standard permissions given only has friend profile picture and name. I used this to get the other information:

```
$params = array(
    'scope' => 'email, friends_likes, user_about_me, friends_about_me, friends_location, friends_website, friends_work_history, friends_education_history'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

}
```

So now when I log in on my page, Facebook asks me if I'm willing to give those permissions to the application, so that is a good sign.

The problem is I'm still not able to figure out how to get the information. When I try and do

```
print_r($friends);
```

or

```
print_r($friends["data");
```

I still just get an array with name and ID.

Why am I not seeing the extra information?

This is not the full code, but a lot of it (most came from the example.php from the main Facebook GitHub account):

```
<?php
    if ($user):
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name']; ?> <br />
    <?php echo "Location: " . $user_profile['location']['name']; ?> <br />
    <?php echo "Bio: " . $user_profile['bio']; ?> <br />

    <?php
        foreach($user_profile['work'] as $work) {
            echo "Work: " . $work['employer']['name'];?><br />
    <?php   echo "Position: " . $work['position']['name'];?><br />
    <?php
        }
    ?>

    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture?type=large">

    <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
    <pre><?php
    print_r($friends);
    ?></pre>

    <?php
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {
            echo '<li>';

            echo '<div class="pic">';
            echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture?type=large"/>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="picName">'.$value["name"].'</div>';
            echo '<div class="location">'.$value["location"]["name"];
            echo '<div class="bio">'.$value["bio"];

            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

The API call (note I made the $permissions just for testing to be sure I was getting it, and they are showing up).

```
if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $permissions = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s your actual API call that you’re trying to get the data with?

Comment: @CBroe - I added them at the bottom-I think that's what you were asking about...

Comment: You have to ask for the extra info that you want specifically, something like [/me/friends?fields=name,location,education](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Dname%2Clocation%2Ceducation)

Answer (score 0):

Your API call to `/me/friends` is incorrect. You need to do something like:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('me/friends?fields=birthday,location,about...');
```

You need to add in the extra fields you require as parameters in the API call. I've added a few in the above example, but you will need to add the remaining ones.